# Rendering a CALayer's contents that Appear outside of Window

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, calayer, cgcontext

So I've got a big `CALayer` in an `NSView` that is larger than my window (using `Cocoa` on `Mac OS X`).

Every time I use `renderInContext`: the only thing that renders is what's viewable in the window, and nothing outside it.

How can I create a bitmap of something outside my visible Rect and export it as a PNG?

I've looked at a bunch of `Core Graphics` methods but can't find the answer anywhere:(

Comment: You could chop it up and put each one in a different hidden view, inside the windows bounds. This may or may not be possible in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be really easy

```
myLayer.masksToBounds = false
```

This removes the mask the main window puts on the CALayer and allows it to be exported, even though you can't see it.